# Which is the best rechargeable 9v battery with high capacity?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I was looking for rechargeable 9v batteries with high capacity?
I found "Energizer Ultimate Lithium - Battery 9V Li 1200mAh" on that site bellow.

http://www.com-solutions.co.uk/products/Supplies/Batteries/Energizer/635236-Energizer-Ultimate-Lithium-Battery-9V-Li-1200-mA?prodid=1285097&info=8

But there is not nothing written about rechargeable property!
I need to know: is "Energizer Ultimate Lithium - Battery 9V Li 1200mAh" as a rechargeable battery?

Or is this "Energizer Advanced Lithium 9V Battery" as a rechargeable battery?

[http://www.amazon.com/Energizer-Advanced-Lithium-Batteries-Count/dp/B008OE4I8O/ref=sr_1_1?s=hpc&ie=UTF8&qid=1415025812&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008OE4I8O)

If it is then help me to find another one which has more capacity.
If it is not rechargeable battery, then help me to find any rechargeable 9v batteries with high capacity. Please!

Comment: Questions asking for help on shopping for components are off topic. Questions here should be about design problems.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think the question is not entirely off-topic. Whether one employs an alkaline, a Ni-MH, a Ni-Cd or a Li-ion battery in a product is a design question. When that is figured out, choosing the best battery in one of these classes *is* a shopping question, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are primary cells. Not rechargeable.

Shopping questions are off-topic, but I note that [Hitachi](http://www.horizonbattery.com/batteries/rechargeable-batteries/hitech-9v-600-mah-lithium-ion-rechargeable-battery.html) does offer a product that meets your description.

Answer (score 2):

Lithium-ion ones are quite good. I've tested one of those:

[e³ Li-ion](http://anrieff.net/batterytest/details/others/e3-LiIon-9V-en.html)

It is suitable for high-drain applications (it's OK with 300 mA continuous load) and has capacity comparable to alkaline versions. Ni-MH versions [clock around 200-240mAh](http://anrieff.net/batterytest/index_en.html#NiMH-9V) in the same format.

The only problematic thing is that it needs a charger for 2x Li-ion cells. A standard "9V-rechargeable" charger is **absolutely** inappropriate, it employs different voltage.